# In WordPress, how to rewrite custom post type URLs to use pretty permalink structure

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I have various custom post types on a site with URLs that currently query an ID and I'm trying to rewrite those URLs to use a pretty permalink structure. Some example post URLs:

**example 1:**

current: https://accountability-framework.org/core-principles/?core_principle=88
desired: https://accountability-framework.org/core-principles/2-respect-for-human-rights

**example 2:**

current: https://accountability-framework.org/contents-of-the-framework/free-prior-and-informed-consent/?guidance_topic=0
desired: https://accountability-framework.org/contents-of-the-framework/free-prior-and-informed-consent/1-fpic-definition-and-overview

So the desired URL format is: https://accountability-framework.org/name-of-post-type/name-of-post/name-of-topic-if-present

Oddly, when viewing a post in WP admin, the permalink is listed correctly:

[image]

but the full page content does not load properly.

---

In our `post-types` directory, this is in `principles.php` (governing the first example post above):

```
<?php

/**
 * Principles
 */

namespace App;

add_action( 'init', '\App\principles_post_type' );
function principles_post_type() {
    register_post_type(
        'principle',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                  'name'               => __( 'Core Principles', TEXT_DOMAIN ),
                  'singular_name'      => __( 'Core Principle', TEXT_DOMAIN ),
                  'add_new'            => __( 'New Principle', TEXT_DOMAIN ),
                  'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Principle', TEXT_DOMAIN ),
                  'new_item'           => __( 'New Principle', TEXT_DOMAIN ),
                  'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Principle', TEXT_DOMAIN ),
                  'view_item'          => __( 'View Principle', TEXT_DOMAIN ),
                  'all_items'          => __( 'All Principles', TEXT_DOMAIN ),
                  'search_items'       => __( 'Search Principles', TEXT_DOMAIN )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'publicly_queryable'  => true,
            'exclude_from_search' => false,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => __( 'core-principles', TEXT_DOMAIN ), 'with_front' => false ),
            'show_in_menu' => true,
            'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'revisions' ),
            'menu_position' => 6,
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-thumbs-up'
        )
    );
}
```

and this is in `guidance.php` (governing the second example post above):

```
<?php

/**
 * Guidances
 */

namespace App;

add_action('init', '\App\guidance_post_type');
function guidance_post_type() {
    register_post_type(
        'guidance',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                  'name'               => __('Operational Guidance', TEXT_DOMAIN),
                  'singular_name'      => __('Operational Guidance', TEXT_DOMAIN),
                  'add_new'            => __('New Operational Guidance', TEXT_DOMAIN),
                  'add_new_item'       => __('Add New Operational Guidance', TEXT_DOMAIN),
                  'new_item'           => __('New Opertional Guidance', TEXT_DOMAIN),
                  'edit_item'          => __('Edit Operational Guidance', TEXT_DOMAIN),
                  'view_item'          => __('View Operational Guidance', TEXT_DOMAIN),
                  'all_items'          => __('All Operational Guidance', TEXT_DOMAIN),
                  'search_items'       => __('Search Operational Guidance', TEXT_DOMAIN)
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'exclude_from_search' => false,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => __('contents-of-the-framework', TEXT_DOMAIN ), 'with_front' => false),
            'show_in_menu' => true,
            'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
            'supports' => array('title', 'revisions'),
            'menu_position' => 5,
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-analytics'
        )
    );
}
```

The permalinks are set to "Post name": https://accountability-framework.org/sample-post/

In regard to the first example above, I also tried adding a rewrite rule in `principles.php`:

```
function core_principle_rewrite_tag_rule() {
  add_rewrite_tag( '%core_principle%', '([^&]+)' );
  add_rewrite_rule( '^core_principles/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?core_principle=$matches[1]','top' );
}
add_action('init', 'core_principle_rewrite_tag_rule', 10, 0);
```

But no dice. How can I set all these custom post type URLs to follow the desired format?

I'm using WordPress Version 5.2.4 with the Sage starter theme: https://roots.io/sage/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Some servers if your permissions aren’t set correctly this may not work and you may have to update your .htaccess file manually.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Important: If you are modifying an existing .htaccess file make sure to back up the file on your computer first just incase you mess anything up.

or

Auto Flush Rewrite Rules

Another cause of 404 errors is whenever a new post type is registered you have to “flush” your rewrite rules in WordPress. This can be done by going to Settings > Permalinks and clicking the save button (mentioned in the first section of this post).

If you are working on a custom theme or plugin with registered post types you may want to consider automatically flushing the rewrite rules for your end user when they activate your theme or plugin to prevent any 404 errors. Below is an example of the code you can use:

```
// Code for themes
add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'flush_rewrite_rules' );

// Code for plugins
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'flush_rewrite_rules' );
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'myplugin_flush_rewrites' );
function myplugin_flush_rewrites() {
    // call your CPT registration function here (it should also be hooked into 'init')
    myplugin_custom_post_types_registration();
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

Comment: I do have that in my .htaccess file and have re-saved the permalinks page but https://accountability-framework.org/core-principles/2-respect-for-human-rights/ is still not loading content. The page is loading though so maybe the permalinks are working but there's something going wrong with the post type?